# Chrome extension for speech to text

Tags: google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Which is the best extension for speech-to-text across websites? I want a free tool for voice-to-text conversion. And something that has a good accuracy too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two extensions you can try. I'll add more if I find any better.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-in-voice-typing/pjnefijmagpdjfhhkpljicbbpicelgko?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speech-recognition-anywhe/kdnnmhpmcakdilnofmllgcigkibjonof?hl=en

Comment: Please understand that questions asking for recommendations should be flagged or close-voted instead of answered.

Answer (score 1):

I really like LipSurf ! Did you try it ?

Comment: Haven't tried it anytime. Will do now.  How is the accuracy?

Comment: It has scroll controls too. Did you check that out?

Comment: Please understand that questions asking for recommendations should be flagged or close-voted instead of answered.